# Firemonkey GCM notification inside local android service

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

Is it possible possible to receive Google Cloud Messages within a local android service (TAndroidService)?

I have tried it with TKinveyProvider and TPushServiceConnection, but when I debug it, I get an "Activity not found, maybe you are in a service" error.

When using TPushServiceConnection in an application it only worked when I included FMX.PushNotification.Android. But when I include FMX.PushNotification.Android in a service I get the error: "Activity not found, maybe you are in a service"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi 10 Seattle Android service (TAndroidService) receiving GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546294/delphi-10-seattle-android-service-tandroidservice-receiving-gcm)  please don't ask the same question multiple times

Comment: The first question was marked duplicate. But I did not se a solution to my problem in the refferenced question.

Comment: If you disagree with that closure, make your case there. But please don't ask the same question again.